# Sorting an array of integers in alternate fashion using qsort function.

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

/*I recently learnt qsort function. This c code is giving incorrect output. Need help with this.
PROBLEM- Sorting an array of integers in alternate fashion. (the elements at even indices and those at odd indices are sorted separately)
OUTPUT- 0 4 1 2 5 8 7 5 9 3
        10 5
*/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// This function is used in qsort to decide the relative order
// of elements at addresses p and q.
int comparator(const void *p, const void *q)
{
    // Get the values at given addresses
    int l = *(const int *)p;
    int r = *(const int *)q;

    return (l-r);
}

// A utility function to print an array
void printArr(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i = i+1)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
}

// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,4,7,2,9,3,0,8,6,5};

    int size0 = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int size1 = (int) ((float)sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) / 2 + 0.5);
    int size2 = size0 - size1;

    qsort((void *)arr+1, size2, 2*sizeof(arr[0]), comparator);   
    //sort odd positions

    qsort((void *)arr, size1, 2*sizeof(arr[0]), comparator);
    //sort even positions

    printf("Output array is\n");
    printArr(arr, size0);
    printf("\n%d %d", size0, size1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question has no solution, as it stands.   `qsort()` implicitly assumes the things it is sorting are in a contiguous array, with no gaps between elements.    That is fundamental to how it both compares and swaps elements.     Because of that, writing a comparator is unsufficient to get `qsort()` to sort odd and even elements independently - because a comparator cannot affect how `qsort()` does swapping.

Comment: This looks like a class assignment for which you are intended to write your own code to sort data and not to use `qsort`.

Comment: @@EricPostpischil - I read a question online which told to answer this specifically using qsort.

Comment: @Peter - Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use `qsort()` for sorting of even/odd elements separately.
However, the setup must be changed slightly to accomplish this.

As Peter mentioned correctly (and I didn't consider before as I must admit) sorting for even elements will "destroy" the result for odd elements as swapping considers the element size which is denoted as pair of even *and* odd element.

This in mind, a solution can be done for all that if the result of first sorting is saved before second sorting is done.

In my sample, I copied the relevant elements after first sorting and merged them in after second sorting.

This is my sample `testQSortEvenOdd.c`:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compEven(const int *p1, const int *p2)
{
  return (p1[0] > p2[0]) - (p1[0] < p2[0]);
}

int compOdd(const int *p1, const int *p2)
{
  return (p1[1] > p2[1]) - (p1[1] < p2[1]);
}

void printArray(size_t n, int *arr, int step)
{
  for (; n--; arr += step) printf(" %d", *arr);
  putchar('\n');
}

int main()
{
  int arr[] = { 1, 4, 7, 2, 9, 3, 0, 8, 6, 5 };
  enum { size = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr };
  assert(!(size & 1));
  /* sort odd positions */
  qsort(arr, (size + 1) / 2, 2 * sizeof *arr,
    (int(*)(const void*, const void*))&compOdd);
  /* output of sorted array for odd positions */
  puts("Odd elements sorted:");
  printArray(size / 2, arr + 1, 2);
  int arrRes[(size + 1) / 2];
  for (size_t i = 1; i < size; i += 2) arrRes[i / 2] = arr[i];
  /* sort even positions */
  qsort(arr, (size + 1) / 2, 2 * sizeof *arr,
    (int(*)(const void*, const void*))&compEven);
  /* output of sorted array for even positions */
  puts("Even elements sorted:");
  printArray((size + 1) / 2, arr, 2);
  /* merge array with copy */
  for (size_t i = 1; i < size; i += 2) arr[i] = arrRes[i / 2];
  puts("Merged elements:");
  printArray(size, arr, 1);
  /* done */
  return 0;
}
```

Tested in Cygwin on Windows 10 (64 bit):

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 6.4.0

$ gcc -std=c11 -o testQSortEvenOdd testQSortEvenOdd.c 

$ ./testQSortEvenOdd
Odd elements sorted:
 2 3 4 5 8
Even elements sorted:
 0 1 6 7 9
Merged elements:
 0 2 1 3 6 4 7 5 9 8

$
```

Some additional notes:

1. The way I (and the questioner) used `qsort()`, it handles two consecutive `int` values at once. Hence, it must be granted that the array has an appropriate number of elements. (Otherwise, `qsort()` either does out-of-bound access or cannot consider the last element.) To consider this fact, I inserted the

   `assert(!(size & 1));`

   which can be read as "Assure that the array has an even number of elements."
2. I decided to make separate functions `compEven()` and `compOdd()` as IMHO it simplified things. I changed the signature of both to my needs and got complains (warnings) from gcc about wrong function signature. Therefore, I casted the function pointers to the expected type (to make gcc silent).
3. Jonathon gave a nice hint to make the comparison functions robust against underflow issues. `return p1[0] - p2[0];` can cause wrong results when the difference becomes greater than `INT_MAX` or smaller than `INT_MIN`. Instead he recommends to use:

   `return (p1[0] > p2[0]) - (p1[0] < p2[0]);`

   which never can have any overflow/underflow issues.

How it works:

In case `a < b`: `(a > b) - (a < b)` ⇒ `0 - 1` ⇒ `-1`

In case `a == b`: `(a > b) - (a < b)` ⇒ `0 - 0` ⇒ `0`

In case `a > b`: `(a > b) - (a < b)` ⇒ `1 - 0` ⇒ `1`

Very clever Jonathan Leffler – I'm impressed.

Comment: On the sample data, your comparators are safe, but if the numbers can be arbitrarily large and negative (the general case), then you can get overflow from the subtraction. One way to avoid that is `return (p1[0] > p2[0]) - (p1[0] < p2[0]);`, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good point - good fix. I edit this into my sample. (I had written a comment which I deleted afterwards where I described actually that issue.)

Comment: It's a nice compact notation, but I learned it here on SO (a few years ago, now).  It has the demerit of requiring the explanation you gave.  Also, in a more general case where you're comparing structures or multiple elements of an array and you need to 'move on to the next field on equality' then the long-hand version ends up being more extensible: `if (p1[0] < p2[0]) return -1; else if (p1[0] > p2[0]) return +1; else if (p1[1] < p2[1]) return -1; else if (p1[1] > p2[1]) return +1; … else return 0;`.  None of which detracts from your answer.

Answer (score 2):

[qsort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort):

> void qsort( void *ptr, size_t count, size_t size,
>               int (*comp)(const void *, const void *) );
>
> Sorts the given array pointed to by ptr in ascending order. The array contains count elements of **size** bytes. Function pointed to by comp is used for object comparison.
>
> ptr   -   pointer to the array to sort
>
> count -   number of element in the array
>
> **size    -   size of each element in the array in bytes**
>
> comp  -   comparison function which returns ​a negative integer value if
>   the first argument is less than the second,

In your program, you are passing **size of each element** as `2*sizeof(arr[0])` which results in 8 bytes which is incorrect input to `qsort()`. Hence you are getting incorrect output.

Comment: I didn't consider the swapping (my fault). In this case, the following might work (which needs rather small changes of the code): `qsort()` array for odd elements (swapping even as well), output result for odd elements, `qsort()` array for even elements, output result for even elements. The most critical thing might become out of bound access. Hence, an appropriate number of dummy elements with e.g. `INT_MAX` value should be added before and excluded from output afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

`qsort` needs a contiguous block of memory to function properly.

If you need to sort odd and even indexed elements separately, you could start by separating the elements, sort them indipendently and then merge the two parts.

You can do that even without allocating any extra memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int less_int(const void *lhs, const void *rhs)
{
    return *(const int *)lhs < *(const int *)rhs ? -1
        : *(const int *)lhs > *(const int *)rhs ? 1 : 0;
}

int greater_int(const void *lhs, const void *rhs)
{
    return *(const int *)lhs > *(const int *)rhs ? -1
        : *(const int *)lhs < *(const int *)rhs ? 1 : 0;
}

void sort_ascending(int* arr, size_t n)
{
    qsort(arr, n, sizeof *arr, less_int);
}

void sort_descending(int* arr, size_t n)
{
    qsort(arr, n, sizeof *arr, greater_int);
}

inline void swap_int(int* a, int* b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

size_t partition_odd_even(int* arr, size_t n )
{
    size_t n_odds = n - n / 2;
    for (size_t i = 1, j = n_odds + n_odds % 2; i < n_odds; i += 2, j += 2)
    {
        swap_int(arr + i, arr + j);
    }
    return n_odds;
}

void interleave_odd_even(int* arr, size_t n )
{
    size_t n_odds = n - n / 2;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n_odds; ++i )
    {
        for (size_t j = n_odds - i; j < n_odds + i; j += 2)
        {
            swap_int(arr + j, arr + j + 1);
        }
    }
}

void print_arr(int* arr, size_t n);

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {1, 4, 7, 2, 9, 3, 0, 8, 6, 5};
    size_t arr_size = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;
    print_arr(arr, arr_size);

    size_t n_odds = partition_odd_even(arr, arr_size);
    size_t n_evens = arr_size - n_odds;
//  print_arr(arr, arr_size);

    sort_ascending(arr, n_odds);
//  print_arr(arr, n_odds);

    sort_descending(arr + n_odds, n_evens);
//  print_arr(arr + n_odds, n_evens);

    interleave_odd_even(arr, arr_size);
    print_arr(arr, arr_size);

    return 0;
}

void print_arr(int* arr, size_t n)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf(" %d", arr[i]);  
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Which gives:

```
 1 4 7 2 9 3 0 8 6 5
 0 8 1 5 6 4 7 3 9 2
```

**EDIT**

As noted in the comments below by [greybeard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3789665/greybeard) the code above is not really time efficient as the merge part is O(N²). Using a temporary array which contains only the elements to be sorted in a particular way, the following program only need O(N) extra time and O(N/K) space, where K is the number of different sorting order needed (2 in OP's question).

[Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) also pointed out that it could be made more general allowing the algorithm *"to handle 3, 4, … N evenly interlaced sub-arrays, possibly with different sort orders for each"*. I implemented it in the following snippet by passing to the sort function an array of pointer to compare functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// compare functions
typedef int (*PCMPFN)(const void*, const void*);

int ascending_cmp_int(const void *lhs, const void *rhs)
{
    return *(const int *)lhs < *(const int *)rhs ? -1
        : *(const int *)lhs > *(const int *)rhs ? 1 : 0;
}

int descending_cmp_int(const void *lhs, const void *rhs)
{
    return *(const int *)lhs > *(const int *)rhs ? -1
        : *(const int *)lhs < *(const int *)rhs ? 1 : 0;
}

// This function is never called. Whithout knowing the actual implementation
// of 'qsort' we can't make any assumption
int untouched_cmp_int(const void *lhs, const void *rhs)
{
    (void)lhs;  // Those parameters are unused here, this is to avoid a warning
    (void)rhs; 
    return 0;
}

// Copy the elements of the source array starting from index 'start' with stride 'step'
size_t strided_split(int* dest, const int *src, size_t n, size_t start, size_t step)
{
    size_t j = 0;
    for (size_t i = start; i < n; i += step, ++j)
    {
        dest[j] = src[i];
    }
    return j;
}

// Inverse of the previous
void strided_merge(int* dest, const int *src, size_t n, size_t start, size_t step)
{
    for (size_t i = start, j = 0; j < n; i += step, ++j)
    {
        dest[i] = src[j];
    }
}

// Apply different sort orders to different elements
void alternate_sort(int* arr, const size_t n, PCMPFN comps[], const size_t k)
{
    int tmp[n/k + 1];         // Please note that VLA are optional in C11

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < k; ++i )
    {
        if ( comps[i] == untouched_cmp_int )
            continue;
        // First select the elements 
        size_t n_copied = strided_split(tmp, arr, n, i, k);
        // then sort only them as needed
        qsort(tmp, n_copied, sizeof tmp[0], comps[i]);
        // Once sorted, copy back the elements in the source array
        strided_merge(arr, tmp, n_copied, i, k);
    }
}

void print_arr(const int* arr, const size_t n);

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {1, 4, 7, 2, 9, 3, 0, 8, 6, 5};
    const size_t N = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;
    print_arr(arr, N);

    PCMPFN compares[] = {
        descending_cmp_int, untouched_cmp_int, ascending_cmp_int
    };
    const size_t K = sizeof compares / sizeof *compares;

    alternate_sort(arr, N, compares, K);
    print_arr(arr, N);

    return 0;
}

void print_arr(const int* arr, const size_t n)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf(" %d", arr[i]);  
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Comment: (Looks like one approach I'm not overly keen to work out: care to comment on the time complexity of `interleave_odd_even()`?)

Comment: @greybeard half O(n^2), I assume. That's only to show that it is possible to do it in-site, but splitting and merging two separate arrays would be easier, of course.

Comment: I wonder, if you're going to write a quick sort, would it be better to simply create a version that takes a 'stride' parameter for how far apart the entries are, separate from the 'size' parameter (in the generic sort case)?  You'd then be able to do something like: `sort_ascending_strided(arr, arr_size, 2); sort_descending_strided(arr+1, arr_size-1, 2);`.  This would allow you to handle 3, 4, … N evenly interlaced sub-arrays, possibly with different sort orders for each.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I edited the answer to make the code a bit more general. Did you mean something like that?

Comment: I was thinking that you could do without the formal split and merge phases if the sort only looked at the odd-indexed entries or the even-indexed entries, and made sure to skip by 2 each time — in the case where the stride is 2, as in the question.  In the more general case, the sort would work on every 2nd, 3rd, 4th, … entry in the array.  Maybe I should remove my suggestion, or maybe I should implement it since I can envisage it clearly. I'm concerned about the O(N²) merge phase. It defeats the benefit from the O(NlogN) sort phase. But it does require you to (re)implement the sort.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It was O(N²) in the first snippet, but in the second is O(N), I think.

Comment: I had missed that change from O(N²) to O(N); that's good.  In which case, you don't need to do more.

Comment: `the second is O(N)[ time], I think` as well as O[N] additional space - what has the world of algorithm design come to. But doing a non-trivial array permutation in significantly less than O[N] additional space significantly faster than O(N²) is, well, non-trivial.

Comment: @greybeard Well, I have missed an (obvious, now) opportunity to reduce the extra space at N/k, I'll edit, "soon"... As a self learner, I'm surely unaware of many algorithms computer scientists take for granted. Do you have one in mind, that can be applied to this use case, other then rewriting qsort?