# C: sorting 2d arrays row by row using qsort

Tags: c, arrays, quicksort, qsort

So, what I'm trying to achieve here, is to use the C implementation of qsort in a 2d array, in witch I want only the rows to be sorted based on the its first element, for example:

```
        int arr[3][2]={{65,1},
                       {45,2},
                       {66,3}}
```

I want the output to be:

```
        int arr[3][2]={{45,2},
                       {65,1},
                       {66,3}}
```

Is there a way of doing this without implementing quicksort myself? If so, how?

EDIT

This is what my code looks like:

```
int f(int a, int b)
{
return a-b;
}

qsort(arr[0],3,sizeof(int),f);
```

Comment: You have to show your effort.

Comment: Use `qsort()` from stdlib.h?

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't explicit enough, I think its understandable now...

Comment: You did provide correct number of elements: `3`. You **did not** provide the correct element size: `sizeof (int)`. As you want to sort arrays you have to provide the size of these arrays: `sizeof (int[2])`. I didn't check (nor can remember) whether this is correct syntax but `2 * sizeof (int)` should do as well. Btw. your `f` is not capable to sort (sub-)arrays. Any reason why you give `arr[0]` as first argument (instead of `arr`)? Though, I guess it shouldn't make a difference...

Comment: Well I only want it to compare the first element, thats why I only gave it arr[0], but let me try it now

Comment: @HugoResende It's not `qsort()` that's doing the comparison, it's you. You pass `qsort()` essentially a pointer to the first byte of your data, so you need to tell it where each element in that soup of data begins, and how many there are.

Comment: What you actually compare you decide in your `f` (the 4th arg. of `qsort()`) but the element size is considered in swapping. Therefore, if you want to sort sub-arrays you have to tell in the 3rd. arg. You may compare with a similar Q/A: [SO: Sorting an array of integers in alternate fashion using qsort function.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47607517/7478597)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not sorting integers, you're sorting "things" that happen to be a number of integers in size.

So, don't lie to `qsort()` about your element size:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int cmprow(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const int * const ia = a, * const ib = b;
    return ia[0] < ib[0] ? -1 : ia[0] > ib[0];
}

int main(void) {
    int arr[3][2]={{65,1},
                   {45,2},
                   {66,3}};

    qsort(arr, sizeof arr / sizeof *arr, sizeof *arr, cmprow);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof arr / sizeof *arr; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < sizeof *arr / sizeof **arr; ++j)
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
45 2 
65 1 
66 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
qsort(arr[0],3,sizeof(int),f);
```

This function take `size_t` as the second argument. You have passed 3. Thats not the size, thats count of elements in the array `arr`. In a crude way, you need something like `3*sizeof(int)`. Or better `sizeof(arr) / sizeof *arr`.
So, change it to

```
qsort(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof *arr, sizeof(int), sizeof *arr, comparator);
```

With:

```
int comparator(const void *p, const void *q)
{
    // Get the values at given addresses
    int l = *(const int *)p;
    int r = *(const int *)q;

    // both odd, put the greater of two first.
    if ((l&1) && (r&1))
        return (r-l);

    // both even, put the smaller of two first
    if ( !(l&1) && !(r&1) )
        return (l-r);

    // l is even, put r first
    if (!(l&1))
        return 1;

    // l is odd, put l first
    return -1;
}
```