# In Xcode, I found semantic issue in the code snippet

Tags: c++

The program tried to compile, but I found out that the error displays, 'control may reach end of non-void function'. I suppose how to do with if condition after putting the return compare. I have been figuring out how to solve this issue.

```
   int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
  {
    if (*(int *)a < *(int *)b)
        return -1;
    if (*(int *)a == *(int *)b)
        return 0;
    if (*(int *)a > *(int *)b)
        return 1;
  }
```

Comment: (a) it’s just a warning and (b) one of your comparisons is redundant

Answer (score 7):

The 'control may reach end of non-void function' shouldn't be detected as there is actually not such possibility. May be, the data flow analyze doesn't detect this properly.

However, there is a much nicer alternative to implement this and it will solve your issue as well:

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  return (*(const int*)b < *(const int*)a) - (*(const int*)a < *(const int*)b);
}
```

Btw. the performance of this code is better as you don't need any branches anymore.

A small MCVE for demonstration:

```
#include <iostream>

int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  return (*(const int*)b < *(const int*)a) - (*(const int*)a < *(const int*)b);
}

int main()
{
  int a = 1, b = 2;
  std::cout << "compare(&a, &b): " << compare(&a, &b) << '\n';
  std::cout << "compare(&b, &a): " << compare(&b, &a) << '\n';
  std::cout << "compare(&a, &a): " << compare(&a, &a) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
compare(&a, &b): -1
compare(&b, &a): 1
compare(&a, &a): 0
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bfa370489c7e616)

I must admit that somebody “forced” me to this nice comparison trick when I answered

[SO: Sorting an array of integers in alternate fashion using qsort function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47608715/7478597).

This is the explanation I gave there:

> How it works:
>
> In case `a < b`: `(a > b) - (a < b)` ⇒ `0 - 1` ⇒ `-1`
>
> In case `a == b`: `(a > b) - (a < b)` ⇒ `0 - 0` ⇒ `0`
>
> In case `a > b`: `(a > b) - (a < b)` ⇒ `1 - 0` ⇒ `1`

Comment: Compilers also know to look for this idiom to optimize, which is neat (https://godbolt.org/z/l80TDj).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use C-style casts in C++.

As you know that you covered all conditions, the last test is redundant:

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
int a1 = *static_cast<const int *>(a);
int b1 = *static_cast<const int *>(b);
if (a1 < b1)
    return -1;
if (a1 == b1)
    return 0;
return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what is the actual type of the objects behind those pointers, you may want to do:

```
#include <cstring>

int f(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    int ai;
    int bi;
    std::memcpy(&ai, a, sizeof(int));
    std::memcpy(&bi, b, sizeof(int));
    return (bi < ai) - (ai < bi);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main point here is that the compiler can’t recognize that your conditions cover all possible cases. => if none of your conditions is met, the function ends without a return statement. You should use if - else if - else here:

```
if (…) { … }
else if (…) { … }
else { … }
```

This will help compiler understand your code better. And you drop once of the conditions.

Avoiding branches is a good idea, usually at the price of loosing readability. Check out @Scheff’s answer for that.